# How to avoid the multiple statements of data in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my page i need to add 10,20,30,40,50 etc to dropdown.For that in my controller i added like this.

```
var resultsPerPage = new Collection<SelectListItem>(){ 
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" }, 
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "20", Value = "20" },
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "30", Value = "30" }, 
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "40", Value = "40" },
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" }};
```

But in code violation showing don't use multiple statements like that.can you give me any suggestion to avoid this lines of code.

Comment: Approach by @Tigran holds good for numeric values . Incase your site needs to be globalized(in different languages) and the dropdown data is Text, your way of doing is the best.

Answer (score 2):

following your pattern may be something like this may fit your needs:

```
var data = new List<int> {19, 29, 39, 49 ,50}; //COLLECTION OF ALL POSSIBLE VALUES
var resultsPerPage = new Collection<SelectListItem>(); //COLLECTION OF ITEMS


//INIT COLLECTION OF ITEMS
foreach(var v in data) {
    resultsPerPage.Add(
          new SelectListItem { Text = v .ToString(), Value = v .ToString() }
    );
}
```